# Get the Sender Auth Token for GCM in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In developer [website](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html)

there is a `Sender Auth Token` in the credentials but how to get it?

Please tell me the steps as it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Written in Documentation like below.

**Sender Auth Token :An API key that is saved on the 3rd-party application server that gives the application server authorized access to Google services. The API key is included in the header of POST requests that send messages.**

you can get API KEY from you from [HERE](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

you can get more informations [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html)

**EDITED**

[GCM SERVER SIDE IMPLEMENTATION IN DRUPAL](http://groups.drupal.org/node/240273)

Comment: Is sender auth token and api key the same thing

Comment: as per Documentation i will say Yes.

Comment: and can you please tell me the Registration id is the device id or is something else?

Comment: i am in a bit trouble Can you please help me.  As per i know only api key is provided to my server so that it can give me the api url, is there any thing else which could be provided to server.

Comment: @zaiff : yes, Every Device has its own Registration ID. that is also Known as Device ID. and Accordng to that Google Server identify the Device and Send the Notification to that Device.

Comment: we have to also add our Device registration id to server while we start Application. can you tell me in which step you are sticking right now?

Comment: yes sure, actually i have to implement the push notification(GCM) and i have to provide information's to my server counterpart who is working in drupal, so that he can provide me the server url. I had followed the google documentation and i got two api keys one Key for server apps (with IP locking) and other Key for browser apps (with referers) , i gave him the key for server apps, now he is asking for a token, but i have nothing except the sender id.

Comment: he is asking that how can he  can add recipients, without token. and getting this error "No Android recipients found, potentially for this language"

Comment: have Edited My Answer. See the Attached link.

Comment: thanks, is there any other credentials which should be provided to him by my side except the api,(not through the code).

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya Does that API key expire ever?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri : API key can be changed by the Developer itself. but it will not expired until Google itself deprecate this feature. if so then you have to migrate or Upgrade your app with newer way provided by them.

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya Cool. Thanks for the quick comment. So till Google itself depreciates this feature, given an API key a 3rd party server will always be to contact the GCM servers without any expiration of the key.